# Volume of revolution qustion

Tags: calculus

Sketch the region enclosed by $f(x)=\cos(2x)$ and the $x$-axis on the interval $[0,\pi/2]$. Find the volume of solid of revolution of this region about the axis $y=-1$.

The answer should be approximately $6.283$, but I have no idea how to get that answer. I would appreciate some help.

My professor used the following method:

$$V_1=\pi \int_0^{\pi/4} (1-\cos 2x)^2 dx -\pi\cdot\frac{\pi}4, \quad V_2= \pi\cdot\frac{\pi}4 -\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}(1-\cos 2x)^2 dx\\ \implies V= V_1+V_2$$

I don't understand this method

Comment: You could start by making the sketch, then trying to recall what you know about volume of solids of revolution. Perhaps a review of your textbook or class notes would help. Then edit the question to show what you have done (and I mean _show_ it, don't just _say_ you did it).

Comment: I believe my professor made mistake and that in V2 it should be (-1-cos(2x)) when i do this i get an answer of 6.283 when adding V2 to V1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working this out in detail because I think your professor's formula
is rather badly broken.

First we have to figure out what is meant by "the region enclosed by $f(x)=\cos(2x)$ and the $x$-axis on the interval $[0,\pi/2]$."
Here's a possible sketch:

[image]

There are two parts of this region, because the graph of $y = \cos(2x)$
is sometimes above the $x$-axis and sometimes below.

If we revolve just the first part (between $x=0$ and $x=\frac\pi4$)
around the line $y = -1,$ we get an object of diameter $4$
(along the line $x = 0$) with a cylindrical hole of diameter $2$ 
(that is, radius $1$) in the middle.
The hole has volume $\pi r^2 h = \pi \cdot \frac\pi4,$
so it makes sense that you would subtract $\pi \cdot \frac\pi4$
from an integral as your professor did in calculating $V_1.$

But
$$
\pi \int_0^{\pi/4} (1-\cos(2x))^2\, dx = \pi\left(\frac38\pi - 1\right)
< \pi \cdot \frac\pi4,
$$
so your professor's formula for $V_1$ gives a negative number,
which surely is not correct.

The outer radius of the solid of revolution at any $x$ should be the
magnitude of the difference between $\cos(2x)$ and $-1,$
that is $\lvert (-1) - \cos(2x)\rvert,$
and squaring this we get $(-1 - \cos(2x))^2 = (1 + \cos(2x))^2.$
It turns out that
$$
\pi \int_0^{\pi/4} (1+\cos(2x))^2\, dx = \pi\left(\frac38\pi + 1\right),
$$
which leads to the conclusion that 
$$V_1 = \pi\left(\frac38\pi + 1\right) - \pi \cdot \frac\pi4
=\frac18\pi^2 + \pi.$$

What you get by integrating $(1-\cos(2x))^2$ is a solid of revolution
of the region between $y = \cos(2x)$ and $y = 1$ around the line $y = 1.$
It is clear that the volume of that solid is much less than that of a
cylinder of radius $1$ and height $\frac\pi4,$ which the integral confirms.

Revolving the second part of the region (between $x=\frac\pi4$
and $x=\frac\pi2$) around the line $y = -1,$ 
we get a cylinder of radius $1$ that is partly hollowed out.
The part that is removed has radius $\lvert -1 - \cos(2x)\rvert$
at each value of $x.$ This is (of course) the same formula as the one for the outer radius of the solid of revolution between $x=0$ and $x=\frac\pi4.$
The volume removed is
$$
\pi \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} (1+\cos(2x))^2\, dx 
= \pi\left(\frac38\pi - 1\right),
$$
which is subtracted from the volume of the cylinder, with the result
that 
$$V_2 = \pi \cdot \frac\pi4 - \pi\left(\frac38\pi - 1\right)
= \pi - \frac18\pi^2.$$

If we were to integrate $(1-\cos(2x))^2$ here instead of $(1+\cos(2x))^2,$
the integral would be much greater than $\pi \cdot \frac\pi4$ and we
would end up with a negative value for $V_2.$

Finally, using the correct results for the volumes of $V_1$ and $V_2,$ it is easy to see that $V_1 + V_2 = 2\pi.$

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

The volume of $y=f(x)$ around x axis is:

$v=\pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}y^2 dx$

The point $(\frac{\pi}{2}, -1)$ is minimum of the function, that is the line the curve rotates about passes the minimum point on the curve. When we say 'around x axis' it means 'around line $y=o$, in your question it is around $y=-1$.so we first transform the equation, that is we have:

$y= \ cos 2x  ; Y → y-1 ⇒Y=1- \cos 2x  $

⇒ $v=\pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(1- \ cos 2x)^2 dx$

Now value of integral is positive above x axis i.e from $\pi/4$(where the curve crosses x axis)to $0$ and is negative below x axis i.e. from $\pi/2$ to $\pi/4$ so we split the interval into $[\pi/4 , 0]$ and $[\pi/2, \pi/4]$to find the sum of volumes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I get a negative number in V2 and when I add it to V1 I get 0 does this make any sense ?

Comment: The area between the curve and y and x axis is concerned. the area with negative value is between x axis and curve and as you can see in figure(I hope you have sketched it) so it must be subtracted:$-(-v_2)=+v_2$